# Adding variables to a fixed model in logistic regression

Tags: r, regression

A quick question regarding the logistic regression in R. Let's assume that I fitted the logistic regression for the BreastCancer dataset with Cell.size and Cell.shape as predictors to predict whether patient is Benign or Malignant.

```
library(mlbench)
data(BreastCancer)
data1<- BreastCancer
levels(data1$Class)<- c(0,1) # binary outcome
data1<- data.frame(sapply(data1, as.numeric)) #converting from factors to num
data1$Class<- data1$Class-1
mylogit1<- glm(Class~Cell.size+Cell.shape, data=data1, family="binomial")
```

This would give me exact model: Y= -5.4771+0.7672*Cell.size+0.8223*Cell.shape to predict patients' class (I would use 1/(1+exp(-Y) as the corresponding risk).

Now I want to fix this model and try to add new variable, Cl.thickness for example. My aim is to fit the logistic regression with the base in the form of

Y= -5.4771+ 0.7672*Cell.size+0.8223*Cell.shape+a+b*Cl.thickness

where a, b are the parameters which I want to estimate.

How can I do this in R? It's not that I want to fix the Intercept but I want to fix some part of the model. Thanks!

Comment: Want is ‘a’ in your new model?

Answer (score 3):

Normally one would update the formula and run the model again like this:

```
update(mylogit1, . ~ . + Cl.thickness)
```

but if you really want to fix the coefficients then

```
update(mylogit1, . ~ Cl.thickness + offset(predict(mylogit1)))
```

Comment: Thanks @https://stackoverflow.com/users/516548/g-grothendieck for your reply! I did what you said but when I compared as.numeric(predict(mylogit2, data1, type="response", se=TRUE)$fit) with  1/(1+exp(-(-5.4771-4.9645+0.7672*data1$Cell.size+0.8223*data1$Cell.shape+0.8155*data1$Cl.thickness)) I found that they are different i.e. the function didn't do what I expected. Do you know why is that? Very sorry for the mess with my comment - I can't see how to format it properly from my computer. Just to clarify: mylogit2<- update(mylogit1, . ~ Cl.thickness + offset(fitted(mylogit1)))

Comment: `fitted` should have been `predict` since `fitted` returns values on the response scale whereas we want values on the linear predictor scale and `predict`, by default, gives that.  See revised answer.